# how should i validate if one datetime field is greater then second datetime in sql server 2008 using IF else statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, validation, datetime

I'm writing a sql query in which i want to check if one datetime field from table a is greater then a datetime field in table b.

Any help would be appriciated.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT A.AFIELD, B.BFIELD, ( <HERE I WANT TO PUT THE VALIDATION STATEMENT> ) AS 'VALIDATED AS' FROM A JOIN B ON A.AFIELD=B.AFIELD
```

Validation statement should be like

```
If (A.XFIELD < B.YFIELD)
THEN "YES"
ELSE
"NO"
```

I'm trying it but not able to do so, it will be greatful if, anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

You want the case statement

```
CASE WHEN datediff(d,A.XFIELD, B.YFIELD) > 0 THEN 'YES'  ELSE  'NO' END
```

Comment: I tried this out but A.Xfield and b.yfield are of datetime data type so '>' or '<' expression cant be used. Any advise?

Comment: See edit above. If your dates are close then you may need to replace the d for days with s for seconds, etc.

Comment: Hi podiluska, Thanks for help. I've used it and its working as it should. But now i've got another issue.

Comment: @Herman - since when can't `>` be used with `datetime`s? This query outputs 1 (currently): `select CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime,'20120921') > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Unless what you're actually saying is that `XField` and `YField` are actually `varchar(x)`s when they should have been datetimes?

Comment: Actually the fields which i'm comparing is A.XField is of datatype = DATETIME and B.YFIELD is of datatype = TIME and i have to compare A.XField's DATETIME value is great then the B.YFIELD's time ( This B.YFIELD's time is from the same date as A.XField). So if A.XField is 1900-01-01 10:10:00.000 then it should compare it with B.YFIELD's value which is 10:00:00.000 but the date should also be coming up via some conversion, so before conversion the value of B.YFIELD should be 1900-01-01 10:00:00.000. Did you got my question?

I'm trying hard to crack it but still not striking. :(

Comment: @Herman - Explicitly converting the `time` column to `datetime` (via e.g. `CONVERT(datetime,YField)` allows `>` to be used and produces the expected results. As would converting the `datetime` to `time` (which may make more sense)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT 
A.AFIELD, 
B.BFIELD, 
(
CASE WHEN A.XFIELD < B.YFIELD THEN 'YES'  
ELSE  'NO' 
END
) AS 'VALIDATED AS' 

FROM A JOIN B ON A.AFIELD=B.AFIELD
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `case statement` for this.

**Syntax:**

**Simple CASE expression:**

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

**Searched CASE expression:**

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

In your case it would be like:

```
SELECT 
A.AFIELD, 
B.BFIELD, 
(
CASE 
WHEN
 A.XFIELD < B.YFIELD THEN 'YES'  
ELSE  'NO' 
END
) AS 'VALIDATED AS' 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.AFIELD=B.AFIELD
```

[For details on Case refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)